# How to get message back AJAX PHP JSON

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I am sending email with phpmailer, I receive the emails when I press the "send" button, but I wanted to stay on the same HTML page, so I used AJAX script with HTML and PHP. The problem is that I am not getting the JSON data back that I need to update my HTML page with the email status and PHP reponse, so :

```
response_array status
response_array message
response_array success
```

In fact instead of "success" execution goes to "error"

Thank you for your help

AJAX IN HTML (UPDATE)

```
<script>
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/mailer.php",
                //data: form.serialize(), // serializes form input
                data: "from_name="+from_name_temp+"&from_email="+from_email_temp+"&choix_gout="+choix_gout_temp, // serializes form input
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log("Thank you for subscribing!");
                        console.log(data);
                        var parsed_data = data;
                        console.log(data.status);
                        console.log(data.message);
                        console.log(data.success);
                    },
error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    }                           
            });
</script>
```

PHP UPDATE

```
<?php

$error = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$subject = '';
$message = '';

$from_email = '';
$from_name = '';
$choix_gout = '';
$response_array = array();

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
function clean_text($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
    return $string;
}

 send($from_name, $from_email, $choix_gout); 

function  send($from_name, $from_email, $choix_gout){
        
    $error = '';
            
    $ot1 = $_POST['choix_gout'];
    $ot2 = $_POST['from_name'];
    $ot3 = $_POST['from_email'];

    if(empty($ot2))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Name</label></p>';
        $name = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $name = clean_text($ot2);
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
        {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
        }
    }
    if(empty($ot3))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Email</label></p>';
        $email = '';
    }
    else
    {
        //$email = clean_text($_POST["from_email"]);
        $email = clean_text($ot3);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Invalid email format</label></p>';
        }
    }
    
    
    if($error == '')
    {
    
        require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';          /* Exception class. */
        require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';          /* The main PHPMailer class. */
        require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';               /* SMTP class, needed if you want to use SMTP. */
        require 'PHPMailer/src/class.html2text.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = "1";
        $mail->Host       = "*****";
        $mail->Port       = "587";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = "true";
        $mail->Username   = "*****";
        $mail->Password   = "*****";
        $mail->AddReplyTo("*****","****");
        $mail->From       = ("****");
        $mail->FromName   = ("***");
        $mail->AddAddress("*****,******");
        $mail->Subject  = "[GOUT] : " . $ot1 . ';' . $name . ';' . $email;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = "
            <div style='width: 640px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;'>
            </div>
        ";
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            $message = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
            $response_array = array("success"=> false,
                                    "status" => false,
                                    "message" => $message);
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($response_array);die();
        } else {
            $message = "email sent";
            $response_array = array("success"=> true,
                                    "status" => true,
                                    "message" => $message);
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($response_array);die();
        }
    }
    else{
        $response_array = array("success"=> false,
                                "status" => false,
                                "message" => $error);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response_array);die();
    }?>
```

**UPDATE**

I have removed the echo lines, and added error function

Results of error coming back from server is **"parsererror"**

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data

Here is the beginnig of the json textResponse

> responseText: "2020-07-28 12:05:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO tribe-nutrition.com
> \n2020-07-28 12:05:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
> \n2020-07-28 12:05:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO tribe-nutrition.com
> \n2020-07-28 12:05:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
> \n2020-07-28 12:05:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
> \n2020-07-28 12:05:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
> \n2020-07-28 12:05:33 CLIENT ->

Comment: *"execution goes to "error""* - So the server is returning an error response?  What is that error?

Comment: You can add one the `error: function(jqXHR, exception) {console.log(exception);}` to your current `ajax` in order to catch the exception the server returned to you. Please add that and update your question for more information

Comment: Also you have some rampant `echo` like `echo($ot1);`... which will wreck any json you try to return later (causing errors in the js handler). You should really include what error text is being returned by your code. It will probably hint to what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You need to debug step by step on server as why it's throwing the `parse` error

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do this step by step with the data coming back from the server ?

Comment: in your php code you send echo($ot1); echo($ot2); echo($ot3); and after the echo JSON data. it cause malformed JSON format. Remove echo($ot1) etc etc....

Comment: yes this is what I have done but it didn"t change anything, still getting error..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with PHP mailer conflicting with my JSON. You need to do 2 things.

You should have a user created PHP mailer settings file. In that file you need to edit one of the lines to stop debugging occuring as follows;

```
  // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // this is the standard setting
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // zero means no debugging
```

Then in your PHP script which sends the email and contains the encoded JSON string;

```
  // Instead of this
  try {  // Conflict
  $mail->send();
  echo "Message has been sent successfully"; // Conflict
  } catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; // Conflict
  }

  // Just use this
  $mail->send();  // No conflicts
```